# Need to know about a good AWS workflow for scheduling a complex set of tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I have a json file in S3 which includes a time string x (in cron time format), duration string y, and a number n.
I have a state machine which needs to be scheduled according to the time x from the s3 json file every day.
If a some job inside the state machine fails, the state machine should run again after a particular duration y for the number of times n specified in the json file.
If the state machine fails even after trying n number of times, a notification is to be sent (I’m hoping to invoke a lambda function to notify).
What's the best and simple way to achieve this?
N.B: I want to use the same step function using different config json files (value of x, y, and n can change according to the config file used). I may need to run the same step function using two different config json files.

I’m a beginner in AWS, and well experienced in Python. According to my plan, I have thought of scheduling the state machine by specifying a CloudWatch event rule, which reads the time x from the json file in S3. The reset mechanism is the hard part for me.

Comment: Maybe you can leverage aws stepfunctions retry after error. When uploading the file in s3, you trigger a lambda that would update your stepfunction with y and n as well as create a cloudwatch event to start the stepfunctions at x time. The notification could be integrated into the stepfunctions.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html#error-handling-retrying-after-an-error

Comment: @AnthonyB. Thanks. I wanted to reuse the same step function with a different configuration json file too, with different values set as x, y, and n. Is it the correct approach if I edit the step function each time I want to run?

Comment: Yes it can be achieved with retry after error. But you didn’t mention that you wanted to reused the same stepfunctions with different json config

Comment: Sorry for not making that clear. That’s why I decided to make it a json file. So that I can use a different config file in the same step function. I’ll update it in my question.